# iOS push notifications for Firebase variable? Possible?

Tags: firebase, swiftui, apple-push-notifications

I am wondering if it is possible to have a push notification trigger in the background of an iOS app when a boolean variable changes on a Firebase Database? For instance, I have a food app that has a boolean variable called "done". "done" is initialized as false, when it is turned to true, the job is done. Can I let the user know when "done" is changed to true?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this is quite possible. It does require however that you have a server (or Cloud Functions) that can listen for the changes in the database, and then send the notification. For an example of this, see the Firebase documentation for Cloud Functions, specifically the section on [notifying users when something interesting happens](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/use-cases#notify_users_when_something_interesting_happens).